# Parse string where "separator" can be part of data?

Tags: c++, string, parsing, std

I have std strings like these:

UserName: Message

At first look it seems like an easy problem, but this issue is in that the name's last character could be a ':' and the first letter of the message part of the string could be a ':' too. The user could also have spaces in their name.

So A user might be names 'some name: '
and might type a message ' : Hello'

Which would look like:
'some name: :  : Hello'

I do have the list (vector) of usernames though.

Given this, is there a way I could extract the username from this sort of string? (Ideally without having to iterate through the list of users)

Thanks

Comment: you can at least break the problem into the simple case and the complex case by checking to see if there is only 1 `':'`.

Comment: How the messages are separated?? with a ':'?

Comment: With a ': '

Sample:

You: think

Comment: Can the message contain a `:`? (I updated the title with the assumption it could be. Correct if I messed up.)

Comment: why do you even combine the two? is there some way to always keep them separated? can you add some lengthvalue to the start of this string (containing the length of the username)?

Comment: Is the separator `colon` `space`, or just `colon`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) like `(\w+?):\ \w+`.

Comment: The problem is fundamentally ambiguous.  Given "name: : Hello", there isn't a way to decide if the extra colon comes from the end of the name or the beginning of the message.  A regex will choose one or the other depending on the how greedy the implementation is.

Comment: Well … most regex implementations are pretty deterministic about it. Greedy grabs the last chance, non-greedy the first.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't gaurentee that the username won't contain a ":" characters, and you want to avoid iterating the entire list each time to check, you could try a shortcut.

Keep a vector of just the usernames that contain special chars (I'm imagining that this is a small subset of all usernames). Check those first, if you find a match, take the string after [username]: . Otherwise, you can simply do a naive split on the colon.

Answer (score 0):

I would use string tokens

```
string text = "token, test   string";

char_separator<char> sep(":");
tokenizer< char_separator<char> > tokens(text, sep);
BOOST_FOREACH(string t, tokens)
{
    cout << t << "." << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is to simply find the first colon. Split the string there, and then trim the two remaining strings.

It's not entirely clear to me why there are additional colons and if they are part of the value. If they need to be removed, then you'll also need to strip them out.